# Reload data when web page is refreshed in Python Flask

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, flask

Hi I know that my English is not good but I want you to understand it.

I created a web server in python using flask.

I import the data from the DB, which is then sent to html for operation

It works fine, but I would like to see the data updated each time I click refresh

This is a python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect,url_for
import MySQLdb

# modify (mysql url, mysql id , mysql password, db name)

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root", "4662", "nomore")
cursor = db.cursor()

# modify webpage flask

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/admin',methods=['GET'])
def admin():
    if request.method=='GET':
        cursor.execute("SELECT gx FROM satcandata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        gx = cursor.fetchone()
        return render_template("admin.html",gx0=gx)


if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

and html code

```
<html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test homepage</title>
        <style>
        table{width:100%;}
        table,th,td{border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <caption>satcan data</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>num</th>
                <th>gx</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <th>num0:</th>
                <td>{{gx0}}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I have to change the method, what should I change it to?

Or, if you have other way, please teach me.

Comment: you are showing the 1 last data everytime, is the database being updated? using this query, you can't have more than `1` row at a time.

Comment: I have created python code to upload data to MySQLdb. This is automatically added to the DB using auto index, and it is executed at the same time as the above code.

Comment: What I want to do is refresh the data on the web page every time.